# SQLSRV 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: php, nginx, pdo, sqlsrv

I connected PHP to MSSQL instead of MySQL. PHP is running on nginx Web server on my PC. I already successfully connected to the database and able to show fetched data in php but it shows 404 not found which is weird.

[here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWOE.png)

and here is my code but even tho i put phpinfo(), it will still show 404 not found but will show info of php.

```
<?php 
class Mssql{

    private $_database = "sample";
    private $_host = "CSRMS-SVR-DB1\CSOFFICE9";
    private $_username ="sa";
    private $_password ="_pass123";

    public $con;

    public function mssql_connect(){
        $con_properties = [
            "Database" => $this->_database,
            "UID" => $this->_username,
            "PWD" => $this->_password
        ];
        $this->con = sqlsrv_connect($this->_host, $con_properties);

        if ($this->con) {
            echo "Connection Success";
        }
        else {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
        }
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM prof";


$test = new Mssql;
$test->mssql_connect();
$result = sqlsrv_query($test->con, $sql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

$someJSON = json_encode($row);
echo $someJSON;
```

?>

Comment: Write code in question. don't ad screenshot.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela, i already updated my question and added code. hope you can help me. thanks